# Using connection that is established in another file

Tags: java, sql, oracle, javafx

I am a newbie in java here and i need your guidance about connection in Java to Oracle DB. So i am doing java fx now and I am implementing MVC for my program. So these are 3 classes that are related,

Util/ConnectionDB.java

```
public class ConnectionDB {

    private static final String DB_USER = "WELTESADMIN";
    private static final String DB_PASS = "123pass";
    private static final String DB_NAME = "WEN";
    private static Connection conn = null;

    public boolean openConnection(){
        boolean result;

        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.100.195:1521:"+DB_NAME+"",DB_USER,DB_PASS);
            if (conn != null){
                System.out.println("CONNECTION DONE");
            }
            result = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            result = false;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Controller/Main.java

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../View/login.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Weltes Oxygen Management");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
        testConnection();
    }

    public void testConnection(){
        ConnectionDB connect = new ConnectionDB();
        connect.openConnection();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Controller/LoginController.java

```
public class LoginController {

    @FXML private TextField username;
    @FXML private PasswordField password;
    @FXML private Button loginButton;
    @FXML private Label labelStatus;

    @FXML private void handleLoginButton() throws InterruptedException {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        labelStatus.setText("Connected...");

        ConnectionDB conn = new ConnectionDB();

    }

}
```

So i need to use that conn variable to establish prepared statement. How do i use connection throughout the whole session of the program?

thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 1):

The easiest approach is you can make ConnectionDB singleton:

```
public class ConnectionDB {

    private static ConnectionDB instance;   

    public static ConnectionDB getInstance(){
        if(instance == null) {
            instance = new ConnectionDB();
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            instance.conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.100.195:1521:"+DB_NAME+"",DB_USER,DB_PASS);
            //...... try-catch or do your stuff
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private ConnectionDB(){};

    private Connection conn;
    public Connection getConnection(){
        return conn;
    }
}
```

Then, whenever you need DB connection, just call:

```
ConnectionDB.getInstance().getConnection();
```